# Overloading Haskell functions to have different number of arguments

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to have two functions of the same name have a different number of arguments in Haskell? This is what I want to do:

`inc = (+) 1`

`inc x = (+) x`

I want to be able to call my increment function with no arguments which defaults to incrementing by 1, or with an argument and have it increment by x.

The I can do either of the following, for example:

`map(inc)[1,2,3]` --results in [2,3,4]

`map(inc 2)[1,2,3]` -- results in [3,4,5]

Comment: You can have functions with multiple arguments via type classes and a bit trickery see Development.Shake.cmd for example. Though I want to add a disclaimer - this is not beginner stuff, more an intermediate topic

Comment: And as another disclaimer -- even in the circumstances where it is technically possible, it's not a thing Haskell developers really do, because it interferes with partial application, which we use *all the time*.  Also it's a pain.

Comment: See also: [Incremental ad-hoc parameter abstraction](https://byorgey.wordpress.com/2010/04/03/haskell-anti-pattern-incremental-ad-hoc-parameter-abstraction/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, the simple alternative is to just take a `Maybe` for this kind of “default argument”:

```
inc :: Num a => Maybe a -> a -> a
inc Nothing x = 1 + x
inc (Just i) x = i + x
```

Otherwise, yes it’s possible, but it’s probably not worthwhile. The technique is to make a typeclass with instances for a concrete type (the result of your operation) and functions (to accept more arguments).

We introduce the class of types that can serve as the result of an increment:

```
class Inc i where
  inc :: Integer -> i
```

If the caller demands an integer, we increment by one:

```
instance Inc Integer where
  inc = (+) 1
```

If the caller demands a function returning an integer, we increment by the argument of that function:

```
instance (Integral a) => Inc (a -> Integer) where
  inc x = (+) x . toInteger
```

Now these both work:

```
map inc [1, 2, 3]
map (inc 2) [1, 2, 3] :: [Integer]
```

But the type annotation is required unless the result is constrained to `[Integer]` by something that uses the result. And type inference gets still worse if you try to use a generic type such as `Num a => a` instead of the concrete `Integer`, or if you make it accept *any* number of arguments by replacing the instance for `(Integral a) => Inc (a -> Integer)` with one for `(Integral a, Inc i) => Inc (a -> i)`. On the other hand, you can just as well add instances for other concrete types such as `Int` and `Double`.

I suppose my counter-question is: what problem are you actually trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. In Haskell, the most recent definition of a function has precedence. So if you defined both versions of inc:

```
inc = (+) 1
inc x = (+) x
```

Then the second definition would *shadow* the first definition. This means that if you call "inc", the second definition will now be used.

However, you can still accomplish what you want with partial application.
If you make your 2 calls curried it will have the same effect. Like so:

```
map (inc 1) [1,2,3]
```

returns [2,3,4]

```
map (inc 2) [1,2,3]
```

returns [3,4,5]